# Relative path in python on win 10

Tags: python, relative-path

All I want in python 3 is to use a relative path on a win 10 PC. 
like:

```
open('folder_for_text\text_subfolder\myText.txt')
```

I've tried:

```
open('folder_for_text/text_subfolder/myText.txt') # this should also work in python
open('folder_for_text\\text_subfolder\myText.txt')
open(r'folder_for_text\text_subfolder\myText.txt')
```

and every frickin' library on this planet

Somebody help me, please!

Comment: What error is your code raising for each of this options? Where in this relative path is your code running?

Comment: if you are using relative paths, make sure it is the relative path from where you are running the script and not where the script is located.

Comment: *All* of your backslashes must be doubled up, not just the first one.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour]. Debugging questions require a [mre], but you haven't even said what the problem is. If there's an error, please provide it in full. You can [edit] the post. See [ask] for more advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running the script from a different folder, the relative path must be from the place where you are running the script:

e.g. if the script is in `Documents` and you are running it from your `home` folder like

```
python Documents/script.py
```

the relative path needs to be from the `home` folder, not from the script location.

Also make use of the `os.path` package. this alows you to build operating system agnostic code with paths:

```
rel_path = os.path.join('..', 'dir1', 'dir2', 'file.txt')
```

Comment: Note that `os.getcwd()` will show you the current base directory no matter where or how you started the script.